# Como colocar 2 background-image sendo um deles semi-transparente

Tags: css

**Resumo:**
Preciso colocar dois background 1 por cima do outro sendo que o que fica por cima deve ficar semi-trasparente de forma a aparecer o background debaixo e sem afectar os outros elementos da página `background-screen2` `background-screen1`

```css
 .background-screen2{
background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
 background-size: auto;
 opacity:0.6
}
    
.background-screen1
{
     background-image:  url("https://definicao.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/significado-de-background-810x506.jpeg");
    background-size: auto;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="background-screen1  background-screen2">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Provavelmente você vai ter que utilizar duas div's, uma sobre a outra, estilizando o background de cada uma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como aplicar opacidade ao `background-image`. Neste caso você poderia criar um pseudo-elemento `::before` flutuante e aplicando a opacidade nele. É preciso também que todos os elementos dentro da div possuam `position: relative` para que o pseudo-elemento criado não fique por cima deles:

```css
.background-screen{
   position: relative;
   background-image:  url("https://definicao.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/significado-de-background-810x506.jpeg");
   background-size: auto;
   color: white;
}

.background-screen *{
  position: relative;
}

.background-screen::before{
   content: '';
   background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
   background-size: auto;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-screen">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```